# Android mobile device not showing in my eclipse browser

Tags: android, eclipse

While I am trying to run Google Maps type apps I try to run using my android device. But device is not showing in my eclipse browser. What should I do ?
Is there any alternate way to run these type of applications ?

my menifest file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: does adb devices show your device as connected?

Comment: My device is showing in my PC.

Comment: and emulator also working fine

Comment: just enable `USB Debugging` in your device.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I enable USB Debugging ?

Comment: what android version you use?

Comment: aha, then go to settings, then Developer Options, tick the usb debugging.

Comment: if there is no developer options, then go to applications, developer options from there

Answer (score 0):

Please Share what you have tried?

where you have to run this Application?

Please check Right click on the **`project->Run As->Run Configuration`** Now one window will show..That contains three tabs like **`Android,Target,Common`.**

1.You should select **Launch default Activity in android tab**

2.You should Select **Automatically pick compatible Device**

Ple try it

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Ple Check this lines from Your manifest flie.. **android:minSdkVersion="12"** know..For Your Mobile Should not Greater than from 12.Please Check

Comment: I selected a project and tried to run as config
then select Target and always promt to pick a device. android device But though myis connected to my pc still it not showing any devices there

Comment: I want to run this in my mobile

Comment: Please check Right click on the project->Run As->Run Configuration

Comment: From Your mobile Settings->Application->Development->USB Debugging

Comment: ple tell me your mobile version number..and tell me from your manifest file android:minsdkversion level

Comment: my mobile device is android 3.1

Comment: Actually in different PC I am able to run that program in my mobile

Comment: R u using micromax mobile or samsung mobile??..For Samsung no need to install any software for Debug. But,for micromax need to install a software

Comment: i am using samsung mobile

Comment: Everything Fine..But,need to analyze where is the problem..Can u post Run configuration Screen shot those three tabs too

Comment: Sorry, I  dnt hve enough reputation to post an image

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Create an apk file with same keystore key you have stored into Google Maps Console and install into your device. Installing into Android device using eclipse will not take your correct SHA1 key to view the Google Maps. As incorrect SHA1 key will lead to authentication failure.

vKj